# error message in beamer

Tags: beamer, errors

I am making slides for a presentation on beamer and everything was going perfect. However,
all of a sudden I cannot compile and I get the following error messsage: 
"! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1"

Please help, my presentation is in 5 days!!! Everything was fine until my computer made a an automatic windows update

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There's no need to panic `:)` Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Five days is usually more than enough for us solve your problem, if it's TeX related `:)`

Comment: These usually happen from a non-text character which slipped in somehow. And these are quite stubborn and can take hours to locate if you are unlucky. Anyway, do you think you can isolate the area? Does not it report a line number? That should be helpful. If that is not the case, keep on inserting `\end{document}` after a frame near the end and moving it up. Use your imagination to isolate it. Then you can simply copy and paste it to some pure text editor. That usually shows the offending one. And, as pointed out above, five days should be more than enough to solve a LaTeX problem.

Comment: It is more efficient to comment half your content. If you still get the error, comment half of what remains as well. Otherwise, uncomment half of what you originally commented. Repeat until you find it. On average, this will involve the fewest runs to locate the error (assuming you have no idea where it might be).

Comment: The error message says "l.1" so it happens on line one. Try deleting that line and retyping it. Or, it is possible that refers to line 1 of some input file. Examine the screen (or .log) output to determine what file and try the same there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (plain)TeX one of ASCII character has category code 15 (invalid). Probably such a characters appears somewhere in you files. Please try to add `` \catcode`\^^?=12 ``  just after `\begin{document}`, as it is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\^^?=12 % Comment this line to see the difference
AAA ^^?

\end{document}
```

If the problem still remains, please try to comment all lines before `\begin{document}` and write down them again. It should solve the problem temporary and give you time for searching the place of the invalid character in your file(s).

Comment: Thank you! I use beamer, not article. Will that be the same? Also, what is 'to coment out'? Also, I did not change anything in the document, it just stopped working after automatic windows update. None of my beamer documents work, not only one of them

Comment: @VeryThankful This was an example of so called MWE. For the beamer class it should look the same, only probably more lines before `\begin{document}` may be the source of the problem. The percent sign `%` is a comment in TeX. All text from `%` tothe end of line is ignored. Hence you can switch between showing and hiding a piece of information to TeX.

Comment: ok, nothing seems to work. Even this simple example:   \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\title{A Tiny Example}
\author{Andrew Mertz and William Slough}
\date{June 15, 2005}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Slide}
Contents of the first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second Slide}
Contents of the second slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: here is the end of the console output: ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 29\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def"
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1

Comment: @VeryThankful It seemed that one of the files was invalid. I hoped that changing the category code will be enough. Now you can change the invalid *.def file manually with hope that it only this one is destroyed. Certainly,you code from the comment produces an aotput without errors.